# Why does lscpu have a different output in a php script than in the command line?

Tags: php, linux, ls

When using lscpu in command line it shows all kind of info. For example :

```
Architecture: x86_64
Byte Order:   Little Endian
Model Name:   Intel Core Processor (Haswell, no TSK)

Flags: fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce....   and so on
```

but when using 
`echo exec('lscpu');` inside of a php script, it only shows the "Flags"- part of the previous output :

```
Flags: fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce...    and so on
```

Why does it do that and how can I get the full output of lscpu. I have read the manual for this command but all the option in there and documentations don't mention this in any way.

Comment: Thank you, could not find the other question because i thought this had to do with lscpu.